# Client side errors using angularjs.org 1.2.15 $injector

Tags: angularjs

I am rookie on Angular.

Can anyone please let me know what could be possible sources/causes for the following client side errors, that I'm facing on my Web App?

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: DEPM-ap01
Loading context root...
Context root loaded
Returning context:  /DEPM-ap01
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=EnvelopeCreationServiceProvider%20%3C-%20EnvelopeCreationService%20%3C-%20dsInboxTasksDirective
   at Anonymous function (eval code:34:504)
   at c (eval code:33:51)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:35:55)
   at c (eval code:33:51)
   at d (eval code:33:265)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:43:84)
   at r (eval code:7:278)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:43:59)
   at d (eval code:33:326)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:35:68)
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=EnvelopeCreationServiceProvider%20%3C-%20EnvelopeCreationService
   at Anonymous function (eval code:34:504)
   at c (eval code:33:51)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:35:55)
   at c (eval code:33:51)
   at d (eval code:33:265)
   at instantiate (eval code:33:462)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:65:482)
   at link (eval code:7:246)
   at J (eval code:52:492)
   at h (eval code:46:28) <div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">
Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$compile/tplrt?p0=dsNavbar&p1=docsphere%2Fdirectives%2Fds-navbar%2Fds-navbar-directive.html
   at Anonymous function (eval code:58:365)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:70:373)
   at H (eval code:96:502)
   at H (eval code:96:502)
   at H (eval code:96:502)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:98:163)
   at h.prototype.$eval (eval code:108:29)
   at h.prototype.$digest (eval code:105:323)
   at h.prototype.$apply (eval code:108:368)
   at g (eval code:71:118)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have declared your Service after the Directive, you are trying to use "EnvelopeCreationService" in your directive and this directive cannot find this service, you have to check:

1 - You declared this as a service and not as provider:

`angular.module('module', []).service('EnvelopeCreationService', fn);`

2 - Maybe you are including the JS of the service, after the JS file of directive

Comment: Hi Leo. Thanks for your answer. Please understand that I facing this issue in a complex project developed by someone else that I'm not able to conctact anymore.  Question: How precedence can be assured in Angular? i.e. how can I know if the Servicis declared before or after the Directive (moreover if both qre written in different files of the project)?